# IE8 Debugger: how to load external javascript files?

Tags: javascript, debugging, ie-developer-tools

I have downloaded and installed IE8. I was playing around with the debugger, but I could not figure out how to load external javascript files. It displays the javascript from the main page, but I need to debug the script in the external files. I have googled various articles that show a screenshot of an IE8 debugger with a drop-down for selecting which script to debug, but my debugger does not feature this. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Screenshot? I have IE8 open, and I can look at external scripts just fine. Are you testing against a specific website?

Answer (score 4):

[image: IE8 Debugger]

Here is what I am seeing when I open up IE8. You just click the URL and it brings up a list of all scripts, which you can then click to load. If for some reason your browser is not showing the Script tab, maybe you should uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: For me, the problem was that the dropdown didn't show at all on my resolution. Would be nice if there was some indicator that it existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the toolbar isn't wide enough (at least 800 at 92dpi) then the drop down arrow will be hidden (you can still click on the main area though). You can change that size by shrinking the size of the console on the right hand side their is a horizontal splitter bar between the script and console panes just click and drag on it.